# Python built-in function source code - round()

Tags: python, rounding

### Problem

I want to access the source code the built-in function `round()`, to allow me to create a very similar function. How can i access this source code and how easily will this be to edit / use?

---

The reason I am interested in doing this is that the built-in function `round()` converts an integer into float even when the number of digits is negative. 
For Example:

```
round(1234.5678,-2)
```

Returns

```
1200.0
```

I want to create a function that returns an integer. I am sure there other methods of achieving the same result, but I want to see how the built in function achieves this task as I would expect this to be reasonably efficient.

Comment: don't know about `round`, but you can start your search [here](https://github.com/python/cpython) if we talking about cpython

Comment: The source will be in C, see [Finding the source code for built-in Python functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions) .. whats wrong with `int(round(x))` ?

Comment: @AlexK. for very large numbers this will create an error, due to the size limit on floats.

Comment: @BryanOakley i did try that, cheers though...

Comment: If you tried it, you should include that information in the question, along with why that didn't work for you. There's no way for us to know what you've tried or not tried unless you tell us.

Comment: @BryanOakley Would it not be healthy to assume that the questioner has already tried to solve the problem themselves? It takes more effort to create a question on here than to google it. I know there are lots of poor question on here where maybe a google could have yielded an answer easily, but chances are the questioner has failed this for whatever reason. If the purpose of this site to help people and also create an archive of questions with good answers, comments like "have you googled it" does not help anyone.

Comment: _"Would it not be healthy to assume that the questioner has already tried to solve the problem themselves"_ - I say that no, it is not. I see many, many, many, _many_ questions that could be solved with a simple search on google, or a reading of basic documentation. Knowing that an answer is easy to find, and yet the OP doesn't find it, makes me think they didn't try. Knowing what the OP has and hasn't researched helps us write better answers.

Comment: _"It takes more effort to create a question on here than to google it"_ - That's the weird thing. It's quite often quicker to simply type some code in to see what happens, or to do a basic google search, or search on this site, yet I see time and again people who ask before doing any research at all. I don't want to post an answer that is essentially the same as the first google result, only to find out later that the OP tried the first google result and it didn't help for one reason or another.

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source seems to be: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pymath.c

```
double
round(double x)
{
    double absx, y;
    absx = fabs(x);
    y = floor(absx);
    if (absx - y >= 0.5)
        y += 1.0;
    return copysign(y, x);
}
```

where copysign is:

```
double
copysign(double x, double y)
{
    /* use atan2 to distinguish -0. from 0. */
    if (y > 0. || (y == 0. && atan2(y, -1.) > 0.)) {
        return fabs(x);
    } else {
        return -fabs(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the source for Python's `round` function; it's the source for the fallback C `round` function for platforms that don't supply the C99 `round` function already (most do). (And similarly for copysign.) For the  `round` implementation for the `float` type, start [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Objects/floatobject.c#L1019-L1066)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I've added an answer expanding on your above comment, as you seem to have an interest in floating point I was wondering if I've got it about right

Comment: @MarkDickinson looks like this one may be more revealing on its implementation https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5fd33b5926eb8c9352bf5718369b4a8d72c4bb44/Objects/floatobject.c#L914

Comment: @nimig18: Yep, that's the one. Note that the bulk of the work is in `_Py_dg_dtoa` and `_Py_dg_strtod`, and those are _not_ simple functions.

Answer (score 5):

just expanding the comment from Mark Dickinson and to make sure I understand it myself, the [CPython `round` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) is spread over several parts of the code base.

`round(number, ndigits)` starts by looking up and invoking the `__round__` method on the object.  this is implemented by the C function [`builtin_round_impl` in bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2178)

for `float`s this invokes the `float.__round__` method, which is implemented in [`float___round___impl` in floatobject.c:1045](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L1045) but there's a stub entry point in [floatobject.c.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/clinic/floatobject.c.h) that I think is mostly maintained by [Python's argument clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) tool.  this header is also where its `PyMethodDef` is defined as `FLOAT___ROUND___METHODDEF`

the C function `float___round___impl` starts by checking if `ndigits` was not specified (i.e. nothing passed, or passed as `None`), in this case then it calls [`round`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round) from the C standard library (or the version from pymath.c as a fallback).

if `ndigits` is specified then it probably calls the version of [`double_round` in floatobject.c:927](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L927).  this works in 53bit precision, so adjusts floating point rounding modes and is generally pretty fiddly code, but basically it converts the double to a string with a given precision, and then converts back to a double

for a [small number of platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29921204/1358308)
there's another version of [`double_round` at floatobject.c:985](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L985) that does the obvious thing of basically `round(x * 10**ndigits) / 10**ndigits`, but these extra operations can reduce precision of the result

note that the higher precision version will give different answers to the version in [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) and equivalent version in [R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html), as commented on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411435/1358308).  for example, `round(0.075, 2)` results in 0.07 with the builtin round, while numpy and R give 0.08.  the easiest way I've found of seeing what's going on is by using the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module to see the full decimal expansion of the float:

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal(0.075))
```

gives: `0.0749999999999999972…`, i.e. 0.075 can't be accurately represented by a (binary) floating point number and the closest number happens to be slightly smaller, and hence it rounds down to 0.07. while the [implementation in numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4f7d5eb13394ec2b13fe9e22855fa009579cb49b/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L596) gives 0.08 because it effectively does `round(0.075 * 100) / 100` and the intermediate value happens to round up, i.e:

```
print(Decimal(0.075 * 100))
```

giving exactly `7.5`, which rounds exactly to `8`.

Comment: Very thorough! I'd suggest replacing some of the source links with permalinks, else they'll become invalid if/when `floatobject.c` changes in the 3.7 branch. As for the last paragraph, there's a single correctly-rounded result for the `round` operation for any given input. Correct rounding is incredibly useful, in that it ensures reproducible arithmetic - if everyone had correctly-rounded `round` operations, then all of R, NumPy, Python would be giving the same results. Python definitely shouldn't deliberately give the wrong result just to match R and NumPy.

Comment: There's also the aspect that as soon as you deviate from correct rounding, it becomes very unclear just *what* the correct answer is. In this _particular_ case, NumPy gives the expected result for this operation, but there are cases where NumPy doesn't give the expected result for a round, too, and it's really hard to pin down exactly what the "expected result" means if you're not going to aim for correct rounding. If you _are_ going to aim for correct rounding, the expected result is clear in all cases.

Comment: @MarkDickinson this answer was partly motivated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974893/1358308 where I tried to explain where rounding errors were coming from.  when I later actually tried to replicate Python's result in any other language I started to doubt that "doing the correct thing" was actually desirable

Comment: Right, but then what's the alternative? How do you come up with a specification for what _is_ desirable? Note that e.g., `np.round(0.545, 2)` gives `0.55` (at least on my machine, and probably on yours, too). Should that be considered a bug in NumPy?