# Why does float.__repr__ return a different representation compared to the equivalent formatting option?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, cpython

To see how `repr(x)` works for float in CPython, I checked the source code for [`float_repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/floatobject.c#L321):

```
buf = PyOS_double_to_string(PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(v),
                            'r', 0,
                            Py_DTSF_ADD_DOT_0,
                            NULL);
```

This calls [`PyOS_double_to_string`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/pystrtod.c#L827) with format code `'r'` which seems to be translated to format code `'g'` with precision set to 17:

```
precision = 17;
format_code = 'g';
```

So I'd expect `repr(x)` and `f'{x:.17g}'` to return the same representation. However this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
>>> repr(1.1)
'1.1'
>>> f'{1.1:.17g}'
'1.1000000000000001'
>>> 
>>> repr(1.225)
'1.225'
>>> f'{1.225:.17g}'
'1.2250000000000001'
```

I understand that `repr` only needs to return as many digits as are necessary to reconstruct the exact same object as represented in memory and hence `'1.1'` is obviously sufficient to get back `1.1` but I'd like to know how (or why) this differs from the (internally used) `.17g` formatting option.

(Python 3.7.3)

Comment: Same result with `format(1.225, ".17g")` => `'1.2250000000000001'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you're looking at a fallback method:

```
/* The fallback code to use if _Py_dg_dtoa is not available. */

PyAPI_FUNC(char *) PyOS_double_to_string(double val,
                                         char format_code,
                                         int precision,
                                         int flags,
                                         int *type)
{
    char format[32];
```

The preprocessor variable that conditions the fallback method is `PY_NO_SHORT_FLOAT_REPR`. If it's set then `dtoa` won't be compiled as [it will fail](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/dtoa.c#L119):

> /* if PY_NO_SHORT_FLOAT_REPR is defined, then don't even try to compile
>      the following code */

*It's probably not the case on most modern setups.* This Q&A explains when/why Python selects either method: [What causes Python's float_repr_style to use legacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920294/what-causes-pythons-float-repr-style-to-use-legacy)

now at [line 947](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/pystrtod.c#L947) you have the version where _Py_dg_dtoa is available

```
/* _Py_dg_dtoa is available. */


static char *
format_float_short(double d, char format_code,
                   int mode, int precision,
                   int always_add_sign, int add_dot_0_if_integer,
                   int use_alt_formatting, const char * const *float_strings,
                   int *type)
```

and there you can see that `g` and `r` have subtle differences (explained in comments)

> We used to convert
>              at 1e17, but that gives odd-looking results for some values
>              when a 16-digit 'shortest' repr is padded with bogus zeros.

```
case 'g':
    if (decpt <= -4 || decpt >
        (add_dot_0_if_integer ? precision-1 : precision))
        use_exp = 1;
    if (use_alt_formatting)
        vdigits_end = precision;
    break;
case 'r':
    /* convert to exponential format at 1e16.  We used to convert
       at 1e17, but that gives odd-looking results for some values
       when a 16-digit 'shortest' repr is padded with bogus zeros.
       For example, repr(2e16+8) would give 20000000000000010.0;
       the true value is 20000000000000008.0. */
    if (decpt <= -4 || decpt > 16)
        use_exp = 1;
    break;
```

Seems that it matches the behaviour you're describing. note that `"{:.16g}".format(1.225)` yields `1.225`

Comment: That seems like a good hint. Do you know by chance, what this `_Py_dg_dtoa` is (it seems to be part of [dtoa.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/dtoa.c)) and under what circumstances it is available or not? Also how could I check whether it is available for my particular Python install (it seems to be as per your answer but I'd like to run a crosscheck and understand more of the corresponding internal workings). Thanks.

Comment: I found a link explaining more in detail what makes python select one or the other method. See my edit

Comment: @a_guest: For runtime checking, use `sys.float_repr_style`; that's exactly its intended use-case. I'd love to get to a place where we can just get rid of the fallback code altogether, but that would mean requiring IEEE 754 format doubles for CPython, which is controversial.